# NGINX Dependancy failure

Tags: nginx, dependencies, configuration

When I try to ./configure nginx 1.4 or 1.5 i get the below.

```
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... not found

./configure: error: C compiler cc is not found
```

So I try and install yum install GCC and get the below.

```
glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 from RHEL-5-64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-58 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (RHEL-5-64)
glibc-devel-2.5-58.x86_64 from RHEL-5-64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-58 is needed by package glibc-devel-2.5-58.x86_64 (RHEL-5-64)
Error: Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-58 is needed by package glibc-devel-2.5-58.x86_64 (RHEL-5-64)
Error: Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-58 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (RHEL-5-64)
```

However when I try `yum install glibc` I get this result.

```
    Setting up Install Process
    Package matching glibc-2.5-58.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
    Package matching glibc-2.5-58.i686 already installed. Checking for update.
   Nothing to do
```

So, from what I am seeing the dependencies are there, so what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your output doesn't look like the output of the `configure` script. More like something that `yum` would output... If you'd compile yourself via the `configure` script it also shouldn't complain about glibc

Comment: @mauro.stettler your right, I missed a step in the my question. I have updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine does not have an active Red Hat subscription. Assign an active subscription to the machine and then try again.

Comment: We have our own REPO as its offline. Even installing from RPM's I get the same issue.

Comment: In that case you need to fix your repo.